# The control panel in Nexus puzzle

Tags: the-dig

In The Dig, where do you get the clue to solve the puzzle in the control panel in Nexus? I'm talking about the alignment of the lens for the power source, as show here:

[image]

When I played the game I had to grab a walkthrough just for that part. But nowadays this still bugs me.

Comment: +1 purely for bringing back great memories of that game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no clue except experimentation.

It doesn't look it because of the odd layout, but the function of the buttons is showing the 4 directions, up down left and right, around the center button, and the two buttons off on the corner serving different functions.  The video shows the sequence being programmed as "go left 5 times", then the other button as "now go down twice", and the center button as "grab" or "use"  When the probe is summoned, it then runs that command sequence to grab the lens.

The bottom left button acts as a "clear all", and the top left as a "backspace".

The second sequence should be much clearer with that information - it's basically go left 4, then go up 4, then use again to reinstall the lens.

There's little way to learn this except to simply try the buttons, pay attention to what sequence you've put in, and watch as the probe interacts.

Comment: Wow this is a surprise! I never found the clue, but never tought it will be by trying. I mean, look how many possibilities. Even by your explanations, still weird. It is haed to believe that someone could solve this without any kinda of help. Thanks for sharing.